# Sending JSON string in AlamoFire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Here is my code :

```
let str :String = "{"emailId":"\(id)","password":"\(pass)"}"

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://constructionapp.dev04.vijaywebsolutions.com/proroffingservice.asmx?op=wsUserLogin", parameters: ["json":str])
            .responseJSON{response in
                self.arrresult = JSON(response.result.value!)}
```

Comment: `let param = ["uid" : uid, "password" : password]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://constructionapp.dev04.vijaywebsolutions.com/proroffingservice.asmx?op=wsUserLogin", parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON{ (response) in
        self.arrresult = JSON(response.result.value!)
    }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably you are searching for dictionary with parameters:

```
func fetchUser()
{
    guard let emailId = IDtxt.text, password = passtxt.text else {return}

    var parameters = [String: String]()
    parameters["emailId"] = emailId
    parameters["password"] = password

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://constructionapp.dev04.vijaywebsolutions.com/proroffingservice.asmx?op=wsUserLogin", parameters: ["json": parameters]).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            if let result = response.result.value
            {
                self.arrresult = JSON(result)
            }
        }
}
```

Better go and read Alamofire manual

Comment: but i want to send this whole {"emailId":"\(id)","password":"\(pass)"} with curly braces also